# RPi3 ACT LED is not blinking/ not booting

Tags: pi-3

My RPi3 B+ is earlier boot properly-with SanDisk class 10 SDHC card(noobs installed). But now ACT LED is not illuminating/ not booting. But very rarely ACT LED is blinking and load to rainbow screen. and after few seconds  ACT LED is continuously ON and display is off. I think I am do all steps correctly- but is there any mistake in any where? plz help.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the reason is a poor power source . Check output voltage and amps on your power source.A good value is 2 amps or higher.